# An alternative to react-native-voice

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to implement a search by voice and I was thinking to use react-native-voice library, that is in the react-native-community.

lib: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-voice

But, as I headed to the issues tab in the repository, I saw that the project appear to be no longer maintaned, so I came here to ask you if you have some alternative to this library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a JS web API that can do speech recognition and Web_speech, here are two links to get you started 

Web speech: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API
Speech recognition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a web API

Comment: Have you solved the issue? What did you used in the end? I am having an issue with Android using Voice.

Comment: I am having an issue with Android using Voice and opened a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596853/react-native-voice-error-on-some-android-phones Would appreciate if you can take a look. Thanks!