# React Native Voice error on some Android phones

Tags: android, react-native, voice-recognition

In one of the devices (Redmi 8A), I have the output of
`Voice.getSpeechRecognitionServices()` ==> `["com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech"]` and voice recognising is not working.
`Voice.start()` ==> `undefined` but
`Voice.isAvailable()` ==> `true`
`Voice.isRecognizing()` ==> `true`

but none of the following events are triggered,

```
Voice.onSpeechResults
Voice.onSpeechStart
Voice.onSpeechEnd
Voice.onSpeechError
Voice.onSpeechPartialResults
```

I tried again after installing Google App and now the device returns `["com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech"]` for `Voice.getSpeechRecognitionServices()` but voice is still not working. Permission is granted and I can record and play using `@react-native-community/audio-toolkit`.

In the logcat:

```
SpeechRecognizer: bind to recognition service failed
ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.miui.voiceassist/com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech.asr.AsrService } U=0: not found
```

Have anyone faced the similar issue and solved this? Any suggestions?

The device is running:

- Android Version 9
- MIUI 11.0.3
- Redmi 8A

Comment: Found out that even if you have google services, some phones can be configured to use other voice recognising services and it can break the flow as React Native Voice is using Google Services.

Comment: Hi, what is the solution you used for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that even if you have Google services, some android phones can be configured to use other voice recognising services and it can break the flow as React Native Voice is using Google Services.

You can check which Voice services a particular Android Phone is using as following:

Settings > App Management > Default App > Assistive App and Voice Input > Assistive App

Hope this is helpful for those who might be facing the same issues.

Comment: What is the solution for this from the app?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please provide more details and maybe I can help.

Comment: here is my question for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219962/react-native-android-app-is-getting-crashed-when-using-voice-recording-or-audio

Comment: hmm sorry, I didn't use the library. So, hard for me to comment. What error message do you get? you can not only look at the react native logs, you can also look at adb logs (native) in Flipper or just console.

Comment: If you use same functionality then please help me into this i will replace.